# Android Шахматы на Java, как реализовать перетаскивание элементов?

Tags: java, android

Я использую библиотеку [chess-game](https://github.com/wolfraam/chess-game)
и разрабатываю Android приложение для шахмат.

Реализовано:

1. Поле EditText для ввода хода (библиотека поддерживает SAN, например "e4".
2. Кнопка для хода, имитирующая ввод в консоль (в edittext введено "е4", нажатием кнопки происходит ход пешкой на е4).
3. Текстовое поле TextView, отображающая саму шахматную доску.

Но это не столь важно, ведь я хочу сделать полноценные шахматы с **перетаскиванием** элементов (фигур).

**Вопрос: как я могу это реализовать с помощью этой библиотеки?**

Comment: Можно через [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop)